# PHP - How to echo the sum of values in a column?

Tags: php, mysql, sum, echo

example, I have a database and 1 table, inside the table is id, user, votes,

```
id = primary and auto increment

users = varchar

votes = int
```

how do I total the values inside the votes field and echo it?

Comment: Can you show a sample database record and your current code?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(votes) as votes FROM table`?? looking for ths?

Comment: check my post i type my database stracture there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(votes) AS value_sum FROM table_name'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

With SQLi

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT SUM(votes) AS value_sum FROM table_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "sum is : " . $row["value_sum"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Please don't advise `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: how to do this in mysqli?

Comment: holy molly! thanks for this answer @Dave it works like a charm. been looking for this for some time. hehe

Comment: @Dave yeah i already figured it out with the help from your previous comment

Comment: @ChumChum : you welcome, accept the Answer if it is useful to You.

Answer (score 1):

1) Query:

```
SELECT SUM(votes) FROM `table`
```

2) Put the results in a variable and echo it.